# What codecs does Ubuntu support by default?

Tags: codecs

When installing Ubuntu there is a option to install some mp3 codecs, does it also install other codecs?

Comment: What is the question? How to install other codecs, or which codecs are installed by default?

Comment: Which of them are installed by default

Comment: The codecs that are not restricted are installed. I do not have a full list. But you can install restricted one from Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred list is:

Ogg Vorbis, Ogg Theora, WebM

To print a list of all installed codecs use

```
dpkg --get-selections  | awk '{print $1}' | grep -iR codec; export number=`dpkg --get-selections  | awk '{print $1}' | grep -iR codec | wc -l`; echo; echo "$number codecs installed."; echo
```

For additional information see

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeFormats